# Gitlab editor Tiptap usage demo

Tags: gitlab, tiptap

I noticed that gitlab editor uses Tiptap under the Hood but I didnt find anywhere where this editor is actually used. Do you know by any chance or maybe there is a codesandbox?

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/tree/master/app/assets/javascripts/content_editor